# Get NotesRichTextItem from NotesDocument directly

Tags: c#, attachment, lotus-domino, lotusscript

My question: I'm in c# code; I had get notesdocument. I can't get the notesrichtextitem (direcly) from document. I just get notesitem now.
So, I need get notesrichtextitem direcly, or to get a notesitem convert to a notesrichtextitem.

I want to add a **new** or add **more** attachments to a RichText field.

Below is some information how I add attachment to lotus document. It's working, but I still dislike this code.
Please show me how to go straight away to do it!??

I'm working with notesrichtext item in lotus, but with my project, I must coding in c#, and connect to notesrichtextitem is the big problem.
Actually, there is no support to get the object from document (lotus) to notesrichtextitem (object in c# ).
So I found a new solution to overreach lotus !^__^@!.

I code in c#.; using .net 2.0; using Interop.Domino 1.2.0.0; VS 2010;

This is my demo code (it is working):

```
 //start demo code   
        NotesItem rtf2 =  dockey.GetFirstItem(RTfield.ToString());
        if (rtf2 != null)
        {
            dockey.RemoveItem(RTfield.ToString());
        }
        // just 1 item is insert;
        NotesRichTextItem rtf = dockey.CreateRichTextItem(RTfield.ToString());   
        rtf.EmbedObject(EMBED_TYPE.EMBED_ATTACHMENT, "", Dfilepath); // set attachment to richtextfield
        dockey.Save(true, false);
//end demo code.
```

as you see, the steps are:

1. getfirstitem ( that return an NOTESITEM)=> I cant no do
   anything to hold notesrichtextitem and use EmbedObject to add
   attachment DIRECLY.
2. delete exist notesitem
3. create new CreateRichTextItem ( with THE SAME NAME)
4. do any you want with notesrichtextitem object you have.

Hope my solution can help any people can workthrough that notesrichtextitem.
I'm trying to understand more about rich text field.
If anyone have a good solution to work direcly with notesrichtextitem from document object, please tell me.

Answer (score 0):

`NotesRichTextItem` class inherits from `NotesItem` class. It has all properties and methods of a NotesItems and in addition some RichText specific properties and methods.

`GetFirstItem()` returns a `NotesItem` object and in case of a RichText item it returns "automatically" a `NotesRichTextItem` object. That's why you can just write:

```
NotesRichTextItem rtf = dockey.GetFirstItem(RTfield.ToString());
rtf.EmbedObject(EMBED_TYPE.EMBED_ATTACHMENT, "", Dfilepath); // set attachment to richtextfield
dockey.Save(true, false);
```

Interop.Domino uses Notes classes via COM. So, the Notes classes should work there almost like in [LotusScript](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/domhelp/v8r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc/H_GETFIRSTITEM_METHOD.html&resultof=%22getfirstitem%22%20). You might need to cast result of GetFirstItem() to `(NotesRichTextItem)` though.

Comment: I'm on the wrong computer to check this (no visual studio installed), but I think you need a cast to (NotesRichTextItem) in the assignment to rtf. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @Richard: thanks for your comment - added casting to my answer - can't test it here neither.